# Enterprise Library config.key path not valid

Tags: c#, app-config, enterprise-library

Having an issue with the enterprise library config key file, it only seems to work if I hardcode the full path. I can't find anything on weather it can work with relative paths or use the root path.

```
  <enterpriselibrary.configurationSettings xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" applicationName="Application" xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/practices/enterpriselibrary/08-31-2004/configuration">
<configurationSections>
  <configurationSection xsi:type="ReadOnlyConfigurationSectionData" name="dataConfiguration" encrypt="false">
    <storageProvider xsi:type="XmlFileStorageProviderData" name="XML File Storage Provider" path="dataconfiguration.config" />
    <dataTransformer xsi:type="XmlSerializerTransformerData" name="Xml Serializer Transformer">
      <includeTypes />
    </dataTransformer>
  </configurationSection>
  <configurationSection xsi:type="ReadOnlyConfigurationSectionData" name="exceptionHandlingConfiguration" encrypt="false">
    <storageProvider xsi:type="XmlFileStorageProviderData" name="XML File Storage Provider" path="exceptionHandlingConfiguration.config" />
    <dataTransformer xsi:type="XmlSerializerTransformerData" name="Xml Serializer Transformer">
      <includeTypes />
    </dataTransformer>
  </configurationSection>
</configurationSections>
<keyAlgorithmStorageProvider xsi:type="FileKeyAlgorithmPairStorageProviderData" name="File Key Algorithm Storage Provider" path="config.key">
  <dpapiSettings xsi:nil="true" />
</keyAlgorithmStorageProvider>
<includeTypes />
```

The path="config.key" fails unless I use the full path c:\application\config.key, but I need to use a relative path and when I try ./config.key it fails.

Comment: You need to make sure that `config.key` available at the same location from where your application is running which in this would be the bin directory of the application. You can write a post build event to copy `config.key` file to the bin folder. Or mark `config.key` file for `copy always` or `copy if newer` by going to the properties of the file in visual studio

Comment: I only have the issue when it's installed on another machine. The config.key file is in the folder with the application but unless I use the full path it won't work.